# send UDP packets over LTE from Android

Tags: android, sockets, udp, lte

I cannot figure out how to send a UDP packet over a 4G LTE network from an Android app (no WiFi). Does anyone have any ideas or know where I can find some documentation? I need to write two android apps, one client and one server, so that I can send UDP packets with timestamps from one device to the other. This is to test 4G LTE network latency from device to device.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DatagramSocket class:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html

This should work regardless of WiFi or mobile connection type, although you may find some mobile operators have some restrictions on UDP connections.

Comment: I will look into this during the course of the week. Fortunately I have 3 LTE research networks and NDA's and access to all the major carriers, so hopefully I can get it to work or get some restrictions lifted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many existing Android Iperf apps that can be used for exactly what you are trying to do. I use [Magic Iperf](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextdoordeveloper.miperf.miperf&hl=en) to do this type of testing myself.

Comment: That is true, however, I was not allowed to use any of those due to lab restrictions.